# What selectors can be inside jQuery

Tags: jquery

I cannot find a complete list (or specification).

- $(document)
- $(".myclass")
- $("#myid")
- $("css_selector")
- $("jQuery_selector")

What else? For example, name attribute can be used instead of id attribute?

Comment: [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of selectors 
You can find it at  w3school for example : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp